# Do I need to implement try/catch expections for testing this method? Not really sure where to start?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm unit testing code for an application and I'm confused on how to test try/catch exceptions. What would be a good approach for testing this method?

```
  public static Exception Create<TException>(string format, params object[] args) where TException : Exception
  {
      var type = typeof(TException);
      try
      {
          if (type == typeof(ArgumentOutOfRangeException))
          {
              return (TException)Activator.CreateInstance(type, String.Empty, String.Format(format, args));
          }

          if (type == typeof(ArgumentNullException))
          {
              var name = format;
              return (TException)Activator.CreateInstance(type, String.Empty, Constants.Strings.ValueCannotBeNull.FormatWith(name));
          }

          return (TException)Activator.CreateInstance(type, String.Format(format, args));
      }
      catch (MissingMethodException)
      {
          try
          {
              return (TException)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
          }
          catch (MissingMethodException ex)
          {
              return new Exception(ParameterlessConstructorMissing.FormatWith(type), ex);
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: What outcome exatly are you wanting to test?

Comment: This method does not throw any exceptions, it creates instances for other code that does wish to throw exceptions. You can do input-output tests as you would for any other code. Such a test would be a good basis for refactoring this frankly terrible method into a set of simpler, typed helper methods that do not need `Activator.CreateInstance` at all.

Comment: I just want an outcome that will prove that the above method passes MSUnit Test. Or to prove that the code is running correctly.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen! I'll try a few other steps and see if can make some sense of testing this method.